El modelo se resetea al cambiar entre Tabs en flutter
En mi app tengo un par de tabs que comparten el mismo modelo, junto con la "vista base" a partir de la cual se muestran las dos tabs. Serí algo así:
Esta es la "vista base"
Column(
              children: [
                const TabBar(
                  tabs: [
                    Tab(text: "Total cost savings"),
                    Tab(text: "Cost savings per animal"),
                  ],
                ),
               
                Expanded(
                  child: TabBarView(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        child: CalculatorTotalcost(usingC),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        child: CalculatorAnimalSavings(),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),

Esta sería la "vista base" desde la que se llaman a otras dos vistas, que son CalculatorTotalCost, y CalculatorAnimalSavings, como se puede ver en el segundo expanded.
Tanto esta "vista base" como las dos mencionadas, comparten el modelo "CalculatorViewModel", deben compartirlo puesto que algunas variables se utilizan en ambas vistas.
El problema es que, al cambiar entre las dos tabs, el modelo como que se "resetea", vamos, que los valores vuelven a todos a como estan inicializados en el modelo. ¿Hay alguna forma en la que pueda preservarlo?

Para eso podrías usar gestores de estados como Provider, Bloc, Riverpod. También esta la opción de usar inherited widget. Saludos,
